# Javac - Compile .java files in different directories TTM code

Tags: java, javac

Iam not familiar with JAVA and I found a java code (tool) in github "https://github.com/shuaiwanghk/TTM" that is related to a task I am working on.

Can anyone help me writing the compilation commands for it.

Comment: Have you downloaded the project from github? What operating system do you use? The project is an Eclipse project; could you not able to import it to Eclipse?

Comment: I have not tried to import it to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You should carry out the following steps to compile the source code:

- Download the source code. The directory for the downloaded project should be `TTM'.
- Change the current directory to this directory:

  **On Windows:**

  ```
  cd C:\TTM  // assuming you downloaded to the root of drive "C"
  ```

  **On Linux:**

  ```
  cd ~/projects/TTm  // assuming you saved the project in "projects" folder in your home directory
  ```
- Execute the following command on the commandline:

**On Windows:**

```
javac -d bin -cp "lib\args4j-2.0.21.jar;lib\commons-math3-3.5.jar:lib\lingpipe-4.1.0.jar" src\argument\*.java src\dataunit/*.java src\launcher\*.java src\matrix\*.java src\matrix\*.java src\model\*.java src\multithread\*.java src\task\*.java src\utility\*.java
```

**On Linux**

```
javac -d bin -cp "lib/args4j-2.0.21.jar:lib/commons-math3-3.5.jar:lib/lingpipe-4.1.0.jar" src/argument/*.java src/dataunit/*.java src/launcher/*.java src/matrix/*.java src/matrix/*.java src/model/*.java src/multithread/*.java src/task/*.java src/utility/*.java
```

This should compile the sources and put the compiled classes in the folder `bin`.

**Note:** The Linux version is tested; but the windows one is not.